# Passing single char values to SOAP using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I've been working with SOAP and PHP for the last three months and I've discovered that I'm unable to pass through single character parameters to the client using the following method:

```
$request_data = array(  
'sSessionKey' => 'OUR SESSION KEY',
'sNotes' => '',
'iGiftaidType' => 8,
'iN1N2Ind' => 3,
'iContactMethod' => 0,
'iIneligibleReason' => ($is_new == true) ? 0 : 4,
'iDocumentStatus' => 0,
'dStartDate' => $start_date->format('c'),
'dEndDate' => $end_date->format('c'),
'cEligibleInd' => 'Y',
'cCreateNew' => 'N',
);  

print_r($request_data);

try {  
    //DELETE
    $raw_results = $soapclient->UpdateGiftAidDeclaration($request_data);
}
catch (exception $e) { 

    print_r($e);

    return false;
    exit;
}
```

The offending items are 'cEligibleInd' => 'Y' and 'cCreateNew' => 'N'

I've also tried various alternative such as building objects and passing through via soapvar and soapparam, but these also seem to fall over.

I'm hoping someone has come across a similar problem and will be able to help or point me in a direction.

The SOAP response is:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid @eligible_ind value
   at Tessitura.WebAPI.Tessitura.UpdateGiftAidDeclaration(String sSessionKey, String sNotes, Int32 iGiftaidType, Int32 iN1N2Ind, Int32 iContactMethod, Int32 iIneligibleReason, Int32 iDocumentStatus, DateTime dStartDate, DateTime dEndDate, Char cEligibleInd, Char cCreateNew)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Can you add response?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could take a look at the `WSDL`

Comment: Just added the response to the above. Thanks.